# Push list of contacts and render a component with name and number of the contact

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to render a contact list to my calling app, but having some trouble with it ('can't find variable: person').
The component will render just the contact full name and the contact phonenumber.

this is my code:

```
import {View, Text} from "react-native";
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

class ContactScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ContactsList: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Contacts.getAll((ContactsList) => {this.setState({ContactsList})})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        this.state.ContactsList.map((person) => 
          <Text>person.givenName + person.familyName</Text>
          <Text>person.phoneNumbers[0].number</Text>
          )
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log(this.state.ContactsList)` in render and post what that returns?

Comment: Your texts need to include brackets around the content to specify that its not plain text you're writing. `<Text>{person.givenName + person.familyName}</Text>` You also need to wrap those in a View and give it a key. If I know what ContactList is I can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your constructor function to have:

```
this.state = {
    ContactsList: []
}
```

And, change your render function to have:

```
this.state.ContactsList.map((person, i) => 
    <View key={i}>
        <Text>{person.givenName + person.familyName}</Text>
        <Text>{person.phoneNumbers[0].number}</Text>
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Now i'm getting "TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...this.state.ContactsList.map...') 
why the this.state.ContactsList is undefined if he will get populated on the componentDidMount() function?.

Comment: Init ContactsList as an empty array. ‘ContactsList = []’

Comment: Changed my answer a bit

Answer (score 1):

```
Just fixing some syntax below.

import {View, Text} from "react-native";
import Contacts from 'react-native-contacts';

class ContactScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ContactsList: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    Contacts.getAll((ContactsList) => {this.setState({ContactsList})})
  }

  render() {
    const { ContactsList } = this.state
    let contacts = []
    if (ContactsList) {
      ContactsList.map((person, i) => {
        contacts.push(
          <View key={i}>
            <Text>{person.givenName + person.familyName}</Text>
            <Text>{person.phoneNumbers[0].number}</Text>
          <View>
        )
      }
    }
    return (
      <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        {contacts}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should read about [React.Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

In short, the component will go through some steps before and after rendering. one of them is componentDidMount() which you are using in your code. The problem is that componentDidMount() is running after render() method. which is why your list of contacts is not initialised. If you want to create your list before the component is rendering, you should use componentWillMount(). To understand the flow I will recommend to call console.log("METHOD NAME HERE") from each lifecycle method, so you can see the exact flow.